# Gravity not affecting Player when jumping

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an Endless Runner player which at any state can Jump. When pressing space, my player keeps going to the sky infinitely.

It has animation and character controller, but no `Rigidbody`. I used it in script instead.

In the animator I added a `bool ground` and a trigger for jumping.

I set the condition `grounded` to true in transition from any state to jump.

:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLqhH.png)

Here is the code below

```
private CharacterController controller;
private float jumpForce = 4.0f;
private float gravity = 12.0f;
private float verticalVelocity;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    moveVector.x = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized.x * speed;

    bool isGrounded = IsGrounded();
    animator.SetBool("jumping", isGrounded);

    //Calculate Y
    if (isGrounded) //if grounded
    {
        verticalVelocity = -0.1f;

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //jump
            animator.SetTrigger("jumping");
            verticalVelocity = jumpForce; 
        }
        else
        {
            verticalVelocity -= (gravity * Time.deltaTime);

            //fast faling mechanic
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                verticalVelocity = -jumpForce;
            }
        }
    }
}

private bool IsGrounded()
{
    Ray groundRay = new Ray(new Vector3(
        controller.bounds.center.x,
        (controller.bounds.center.y - controller.bounds.extents.y) + 0.2f,
        controller.bounds.center.z),
        Vector3.down);
    return (Physics.Raycast(groundRay, 0.2f + 0.1f));

}
```

Any ideas very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Unity system to handle your [physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html), you are going to have to use a `Rigidbody` component on there.

Otherwise, you need to simulate an acceleration. Do that by increasing the velocity every physics tick in `FixedUpdate`

```
float gravityVelocity = 0f;

float gravityFactor = 0.5f;
float gravityAcceleration = 9.2f * gravityFactor;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    gravityVelocity += gravityAcceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    gameObjectToUpdate.transform.position +=
        new Vector3(0, gameObjectToUpdate.transform.position.y - gravityVelocity, 0);
}
```